# performance of layered canvases vs manual drawImage()

Tags: performance, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I've written a small graphics engine for my game that has multiple canvases in a tree(these basically represent layers.) Whenever something in a layer changes, the engine marks the affected layers as "soiled" and in the render code the lowest affected layer is copied to its parent via drawImage(), which is then copied to its parent and so on up to the root layer(the onscreen canvas.) This can result in multiple drawImage() calls per frame but also prevents rerendering anything below the affected layer. However, in frames where nothing changes no rendering or drawImage() calls take place, and in frames where only foreground objects move, rendering and drawImage() calls are minimal.

I'd like to compare this to using multiple onscreen canvases as layers, as described in this article:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-canvashtml5layering/

In the onscreen canvas approach, we handle rendering on a per-layer basis and let the browser handle displaying the layers on screen properly. From the research I've done and everything I've read, this seems to be generally accepted as likely more efficient than handling it manually with drawImage(). So my question is, can the browser determine what needs to be re-rendered more efficiently than I can, despite my insider knowledge of exactly what has changed each frame?

I already know the answer to this question is "Do it both ways and benchmark." But in order to get accurate data I need real-world application, and that is months away. By then if I have an acceptable approach I will have bigger fish to fry. So I'm hoping someone has been down this road and can provide some insight into this.

Comment: Just to clarify, my engine uses a layered approach too. The only difference is that I'm manually using drawImage to draw my offscreen layers onto the onscreen canvas, instead of letting the browser draw a bunch of onscreen layers to the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser cannot determine anything when it comes to the canvas element and the rendering as it is a passive element - everything in it is user rendered by the means of JavaScript. The only thing the browser does is to pipe what's on the canvas to the display (and more annoyingly clear it from time to time when its bitmap needs to be re-allocated).

There is unfortunately no golden rule/answer to what is the best optimization as this will vary from case to case - there are many techniques that could be mentioned but they are  merely *tools* you can use but you will still have to figure out what would be the *right* tool or the right combination of tools for your specific case. Perhaps layered is good in one case and perhaps it doesn't bring anything to another case.

Optimization in general is very much an in-depth analysis and break-down of patterns specific to the scenario, that are then isolated and optimized. The process if often experiment, benchmark, re-adjust, experiment, benchmark, re-adjust, experiment, benchmark, re-adjust... of course experience reduce this process to a minimum but even with experience the specifics comes in a variety of combinations that still require some fine-tuning from case to case (given they are not identical).

Even if you find a good recipe for your current project it is not given that it will work optimal with your next project. This is one reason no one can give an exact answer to this question.

However, when it comes canvas what you want to achieve is a minimum of clear operations and minimum areas to redraw (drawImage or shapes). The point with layers is to groups elements together to enable this goal.

Comment: So if I have 10 canvases layered on screen, does that mean that every frame the browser will draw all 10 canvases to the display in turn(starting with lowest zIndex), regardless  of whether any changes were made to anything?

Comment: @flancor no, re-paint and refresh are two different things. If there is no need to re-paint anything the content is just pushed to screen (refresh). If there is need for re-paint the browser will try to do all the re-paints within a frame (when it comes to requestAnimationFrame). But for overlapping elements/canvases where there is transparency involved the browser will need to re-merge to a final result if there is a change in one of these elements. If this is optimized somehow I don't know, but it would be browser dependent.